# Cant see split html file

Tags: html

I'm trying to split html file into 2 different files:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<frameset cols="25%,75%">
   <frame src="addNewEvent.html" />
   <frame src="totalEvents.html" />
</frameset>

</body>
</html>
```

addNewEvent.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

Left

</body>
</html>
```

totalEvents.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

Right

</body>
</html>
```

The 3 files (main html and addNewEvent.html, totalEvents.html) are in the same directory.
(I just learning html, so for now, I'm not using server, and open the main page with the browser.

When opening the main page in the browser, is seems that the addNewEvent.html, totalEvents.html are not loaded. (There is no error in console log)

1. What an I doing wrong ?
2. Is it right to split the page into little pages with frameset ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use HTML4? It's the 21st century and HTML5 is de facto for HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What an I doing wrong ?

You didn't use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org) which would have told you that a `<frameset>` element is not allowed inside a `<body>` element.

Frameset documents have a `<frameset>` **instead of** a `<body>` element. Since the HTML document already had its own `<body>`, the browser ignored the `<frameset>`.

> Is it right to split the page into little pages with frameset ?

That's largely a matter of opinion. They do cause various issues with how they interact with browser navigation controls and do not exist in HTML 5.